# iOS 8: Working with resizable iPhone and iPad simulators

Tags: ios-simulator, ios8

1. Where can I get working documentation for the iOS 8 resizable iPhone and iPad simulators?
2. How to handle the View Controller sizeable parameters?
3. How would View Controllers respond to size changes?

Any pointers please?

Comment: Most likely from the Apple Developer Portal.

Answer (score 1):

As for question 1, here is the iOS Simulator User Guide (sign in required):

https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/iOS_Simulator_Guide/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012848

Answer (score 1):

I found elsewhere that the trick to getting the resizable simulator to resize is to enter point values, not pixels, so for iPhone 6 you would enter 375 x 667 rather than 750 x 1334